# Android Studio Network Profiler cyrillic

Tags: android, android-studio, profiler, android-profiler

I have an encoding problem in the requests and responses of the android profiler. When I make a request, in Logсat, log of Okhttp displays the request and the answer in Cyrillic. In this case, the same data in the Android Network profiler is displayed as hieroglyphs. After checking the encoding, it turned out that the Android profiler displays data in windows-1221.

How to solve this problem?